# How to consume web api services hosted from angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have developed one small web api crud application and hosted in IIS server. I am able to do the all the operations. I hosted in the server 192.168.0.213:7777 and it is working fine. These services i am trying to access from another application through angularjs as below.

```
 this.deleteSubscriber = function (user_id) {
        var url = 'http://192.168.0.213:7777/api/User_Creation/' + user_id;
        return $http.delete(url).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
```

Whenever i tried to delete user i am getting error message as below.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.213:7777/api/User_Creation/37. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:26079' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

May i know why I am getting this issue? Do i need to make any changes in the iis or in my application? Thank you...

Comment: Thank you for your message. May i know which header? I am not sure about this because i am new to web api.

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/server_iis6.html

Comment: Is your angular app and web service running on separate ip?

Comment: Yes.. Running in seperate ip.

Comment: @mitesh if i right click on site i do not get properties tab. I get options like explore,edit permissions,add application,add virtual directory and many more.

Comment: whats your iis version ?

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole then you should read up on CORS. And how to enable it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable CORS in iis8 by configuring customHeaders

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,DELETE"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Can also be configured at code level - [Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: Thank you. if i give in controller level such as  [EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "*")] then in methods should i mention PUT,DELETE,GET?

Comment: In web.config i found  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" /> Is it fine if this piece of code is there?

Comment: i edited config file and added piece of code above controller level still no luck.

Comment: For example in controller above delete i have  [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")] do i need to change anything here?